# ReferenceEquals and Nullable<T>

Tags: c#, reference, nullable, equality

While writing a unit test, I wanted to use `Assert.AreSame(..)` against a `Nullable<T>` type and I got unexpected results. Then I realized that the below code fails:

```
int? k = 10;
Assert.IsTrue(ReferenceEquals(k, k));
```

**What is happening here?**

Also, how can I make sure my method is returning the very same instance I passed to the mock/stub and not just doing `return 10`?

**Edit:**

I usually do the following to make sure I'm getting consistent results in my unit tests:

```
//Arrange
var result = new string(new[] {'1', '2', '3'});
mock.SetUp(x => x.Method("something").Returns(result);

//Act here

//Assert
Assert.AreSame(result, instance.ValueAssigned);
```

If I do `return "123"` inside `Method(..)`, the above test will fail. I was trying to find a way of doing the same with Nullable.

Comment: The `Value` property of the nullables are being boxed.

Comment: use Assert.AreEqual() instead of AreSame()

Answer (score 12):

> What is happening here?

Both arguments are being boxed, to different objects.

Imagine your code is actually this:

```
int? k = 10;
object x = k; // Boxing operation 1
object y = k; // Boxing operation 2
Assert.IsTrue(ReferenceEquals(x, y));
```

Don't forget that nullable value types are still value types - so they get boxed when you convert them to reference type expressions.

> Also, how can I make sure my method is returning the very same instance I passed to the mock/stub and not just doing return 10?

For value types, that question simply doesn't make sense. Basically, use `Assert.AreSame` for reference types, and `Assert.AreEqual` for value types. Note that this is independent of nullability. `Assert.AreSame(10, 10)` will fail too.

Comment: I edited my question for you to understand what I mean with my 2nd question.